# How to blur image using Picasso?

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I want to blur my image after downloading using picasso. I actually find a library that maybe can add blur effect to my Image: https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations

And here is the code I use:

```
 Picasso.get()
            .load(currentEvent.posterDownloadPath)
            .transform(BlurTransformation(25,3))
            .into(recommendedEventViewHolder.blurryImageView)
```

But unfortunately I have error:

[image]

I have tried several ways, but I still can't get the correct way to use blur effect of this library. could you please help me to add blur effect? Maybe you have different way (not using this library)?

Java is ok.

Comment: I switched to the library glide because i also had some problems with Picasso. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-custom-transformation

Comment: Glide library https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: @Vince yup, I initially using glide, then change to Picasso because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084585/why-my-glide-doesnt-cache-the-image-it-seems-download-image-all-over-again

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Picasso**

For Using **Picasso**, follow these steps:

**Step 1**

Add this depencencies to Gradle:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.2.1'
    // If you want to use the GPU Filters
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'
}
```

**Step 2**

Set Picasso Transform:

```
Picasso.get()
       .load(currentEvent.posterDownloadPath)
       .transform(new BlurTransformation(mContext, 25, 1))
       .into(recommendedEventViewHolder.blurryImageView);
```

in kotlin like this:

```
Picasso.get()
           .load(currentEvent.posterDownloadPath)
           .transform(BlurTransformation(mContext, 25, 1))
           .into(recommendedEventViewHolder.blurryImageView)
```

Also you can use [Blurry](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry). Blurry is an easy blur library for Android.
But I suggest [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco). Fresco is a powerful system for displaying images in Android applications.

**Fresco**

For Using **Fresco**, follow these steps:

**Step 1:** Create Android Project and add fresco library dependency on build.gradle of module and sync project.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.13.0'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:fresco-processors:2.1.0'
}
```

**Step 2:** Initialize fresco inside your onCreate() method of MainActivity.java or Application.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //initialize fresco
    Fresco.initialize(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

**Step 3:** Inside your activity_main.xml add SimpleDraweeView which is provided by Fresco Library.

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/sdv_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

**Step 4:** Before writing code for blurring image you have to take care of three major classes.

**i.Postprocessor:** -Define quality for blurriness for your image.

**ii.ImageRequest:** -Create request for controller using instance of Postprocessor.

**iii.PipelineDraweeController:** -Prepare controller for view using instance of ImageRequest and SimpleDraweeView.

**Step5:** Inside your main activity class create an instance of BlurPostprocessor with context and radius, where radius refers to percentage of blurness of your image.

```
Postprocessor postprocessor = new BlurPostprocessor(this,50);
```

**Step6:** ImageRequest class Build image request with blur property hold by instance of Postprocessor.

```
 ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.parse("image url"))
        .setPostprocessor(postprocessor)
        .build();
```

**Step7:** Create new instance of `PipelineDraweeController` using imagerequest and old simpleDraweeView.

```
controller = (PipelineDraweeController) Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
        .setImageRequest(imageRequest)
        .setOldController(simpleDraweeView.getController())
        .build();
```

**Step 8:** Pass controller to simpleDraweeView.

```
simpleDraweeView.setController(controller);
```

That’s all, now build and run the application.

Enjoy that :)

Comment: I have tried, but I have another error like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9dSm.png, I am using Kotlin. yes I have seen that Blurry library. but unfortunately I little bit confused how to use that library, I have an image path and i want to place the downloaded image in an image view, but I am confused how to apply that using Blurry, could you please add code to use Blurry for this case ?

Comment: @Alexa289 you must use .transform(new BlurTransformation(mContext, 25, 1)).

Comment: Thanks, but this is the result if I use new https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GdJm.png , still have error

Comment: @Alexa289 Are you sure? I try this and that worked correctly. waht language you are coding. android or kotlin?

Comment: yup, 100%. I am using Kotlin, there is no 'new' in Kotlin.

Comment: @Alexa289 I test this code in kotlin and it is correct. You must use .transform(BlurTransformation(yourContext, 25, 1))

Comment: @Alexa289 If my answer solve your issue, please accept it and give me upvote. Thanks

Comment: I finally find out why I still have the error, https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyEoF.png . previously I add wasabeef transformation for GLIDE, and I choose the wrong BlurTransformation class, I choose glide instead of Picasso. problem solved, thanks

Comment: @Alexa289 Really? I want ask it yesterday!!! I am happy that your problem solved. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me: Both transforms are from the wasabeef lib

```
 SketchFilterTransformation transformation  = new SketchFilterTransformation(this);

 BlurTransformation transformation1 = new BlurTransformation(this);

 Picasso.get()
        .load(mImageUri)
        .transform(transformation)
        .transform(transformation1)
        .rotate(decodeRotation(orientation))
        .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image));
```

The URI is the data of a file picker.

> I have this in my Build gradle:

```
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
 implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.2.1'
 // If you want to use the GPU Filters
 implementation 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'
```