# Why my Glide doesn't cache the image ? it seems download image all over again

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to download image using the code below:

```
Glide.with(recommendedEventViewHolder.itemView)
            .load(currentEvent.posterDownloadPath)
            .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC )
            .into(recommendedEventViewHolder.posterImageView)
```

but the result is like this, in this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ljGxwsi0wpaZbBY_CLmczdBzD9krz4QQ/view?usp=sharing

when I scroll down to the bottom of recycler view, and then go back to the top, the first image disappear and it seems re download the image

I have tried to remove the diskStartegy to be something like this:

```
Glide.with(recommendedEventViewHolder.itemView)
                .load(currentEvent.posterDownloadPath)
                .into(recommendedEventViewHolder.posterImageView)
```

but the result is just the same. I am using this in my gradle file

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your diskCacheStrategy from `DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC` to `DiskCacheStrategy.onlyRetrieveFromCache(true)`, this will only try to send request only if images failed to cache.